# datatables extension works fine, when added from CDN, but not, when added from local Scripts-Folder

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatables

I am trying to include a JQuery datatables extension to sort dates by german date system. When I am using the [CDN file](https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/sorting/date-de.js) as a source, everything works fine. But when I am using my local copy of it, it doesn't work at all. Because I want to extend this function to handle null-values, i need to have a local version of it. What am I doing wrong?

This is my order of JavaScript includes:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/_extensions.js"></script> // this is, where the extension is located
```

This is, where I create my datatable, at the very end of the table (datatable is working, but not sorting by date):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table1').DataTable({
            columnDefs: [
               { "type": "de_date", targets: 2 }
               //,{ type: 'de_date', targets: 1 }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Does anybody know, why this causes problems?

```
jQuery.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    return Globalize.parseDate(value);
};

$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    if (Globalize.parseFloat(value)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    Globalize.culture("de-DE");
});

// Code for the de_date-Sort

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['de_date-asc'] = function (a, b) {
    var deDatea = a.trim(a).split('.');
    var deDateb = b.trim(b).split('.');

    if (!isNaN(x) && !isNaN(y)) {
        var x = (deDatea[2] + deDatea[1] + deDatea[0]) * 1;
        var y = (deDateb[2] + deDateb[1] + deDateb[0]) * 1;

        if (x == y) { return 0; }
    }
    if (isNaN(x) || x < y) { return 1; }
    if (isNaN(y) || x > y) { return -1; }
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['de_date-desc'] = function (a, b) {
    var deDatea = a.trim(a).split('.');
    var deDateb = b.trim(b).split('.');

    if (!isNaN(x) && !isNaN(y)) {
        var x = (deDatea[2] + deDatea[1] + deDatea[0]) * 1;
        var y = (deDateb[2] + deDateb[1] + deDateb[0]) * 1;

        if (x == y) { return 0; }
    }
    if (isNaN(y) || x < y) { return -1; }
    if (isNaN(x) || x > y) { return 1; }
};
```

Comment: Take care when spelling JavaScript to avoid search collision with Java.

Comment: your datatables is still on a cdn. Do you have the css as well? Jquery 1.10.2 is a few years old now.

Comment: Yes, I have the css file. I now copied the Content of the extension-file directly into the scripts-area shown above instead and this works, so i could handle the null values correctly. But it's still not the solution I was looking for. I don't get it, why adding the extension doesn't work. Do I need to mark the extension file in some way? I added the whole content of my _extensions.js (there is few other code inside, that is working), so maybe someone would find the problem in it. The date_de is changed, but it is a function that works, the same I use in the scripts-area right now.